# Understanding Hauffman Compression?

Tags: memory

I'm trying to understand the Hauffman compression algorithm.

Lets assume the word : **YESSSS**

According to Hauffman tree we will get :

- S : 4 times -> Code : 0
- Y : once    -> Code : 01
- E : once    -> Code : 00

at the end YESSSS will become : **01 00 0 0 0 0**

So far everything is clear.

Now my problem is in the space between the binary words. How this can be stored in memory ?

In another words ?

How to computer will know that that :

- the first character has two bits
- the second character has two bits
- the fourth other characters has only one bit

Because **01 00 0 0 0 0** doesn't have the same meaning than **01 00 00 00**

- **01 00 0 0 0 0** means : YESSSS
- **01 00 00 00** means : YEEE

Any ideas please ?

Comment: You have derived your tree incorrectly.  Make S be 1, I'm thinking (though it's been about 10 years since I played with this).

Comment: There aren't supposed to be any spaces in between the encoded letters. If I recall correctly, your entire encoded message would simply be one really long string run-together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoder has to ensure that any long sequence of bits cannot be mis-interpreted as a combination of shorter bits. e.g. in your compressed example, the `00` for `E` cannot be distinguished from `00` as `SS`.

If you look at the example bit string chart here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_Encoding, you'll note that the three most-frequent characters (space, 'a', 'e') have bit strings which do not appear at the start of any of the other longer bit strings. And the same goes for the mid-length 4bit characters - none of those bit strings appear at the beginning of the strings for the least-frequence 5bit characters.

With this restriction in place, decoding becomes a matter of reading at least as many bits as the shortest bit-string in your compression table. e.g. if your shortest character compresses to 4 bits, you never read less than 4 bits of compressed data. If the 4bits you read don't match any of the short chars, you another bit and start scanning for 5bit sequences, and keep adding bits until you find a match. Then you start over with another 4 bits.

Adding a separator character defeats the purpose of compressing the data. You'd be increasing your compression alphabet from `n` characters, to `n+1`, and by the nature of the compression, the separator will likely have a "longer" bit sequence than average. That means if you have large quantities of "short" sequence characters, you'd probably be blowing each character's compressed space requirement past what it originally took.

e.g. a 7bit separator between a sequence of chars that has only 3 bits of each char means you now are taking up 10 bits per character - having blown your data up in size by around 20%: 8bit -> 10bit required.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this interpretation is that your chosen codes are not "uniquely decodeable", that is you cannot determine which "path" of the tree to follow by just the given code. A correct Huffman coding of your given example is:

- S = 0
- E = 10
- Y = 11

It should be clear then that a decoder can decide which path of the tree to follow to decode it.

**YESSSS** = **11 10 0 0 0 0**

Where the 1's in a way indicate that those are 2-bit codes.

Edit: Didn't read about the "space". As Marc says, you won't need any separator. This coding is designed to make a stream of bits without spaces, because such spaces would take up space, reducing the effectiveness of compression.

Comment: The important point is that the first N digits of an M-digit code (where M > N) be distinct from the digits that denote any N-digit code.